# SubSonic 3.0.0.3 Calling Stored Procedure Issue

Tags: c#, .net, stored-procedures, subsonic, subsonic3

I have updated the subsonic reference from 3.0.0.0 to 3.0.0.3, when I try to execute a stored procedure then I get a following error

Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to varchar is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

I am calling the store procedure as follows

```
db.GetAllLoanApplications(orderBy, direction, userEmail,"","","", 
                          Convert.ToString(userId)).ExecuteReader();
```

GetAllLoanApplications is the Stored Procedure Name

Please tell me how I will be able to fix this issue,

Regards,
Muhammad Naveed Khan

Comment: Which database are you calling the SPs in?

Answer (score 1):

This issue was fixed with 3.0.0.3 - are you sure your reference is updated? If so - please submit an issue and as much detail as possible.